# Not Ready json javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "local": "padaria",
            "item1": "leite",
            "item2": "pao"
        }

    ],
}
```

The problem is that I'm not managing to go a `JSON`, and am getting this error:

> Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: item1 is not defined

My code:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(retorno);

for (var i = 0; i < obj[0].Items.length; i++) {
    function getObjectLength(obj) {
        var length = 0;

        for (var p in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                length++;
            }
        }

        return length;
    }

    var t;

    for (var a = 0; a < getObjectLength(obj[0].Items[i]); a++) {
        if (a > 0) {
            t = (obj[0].Items[i].
                'item' + a);
        }

        console.log(obj[0].Items[i].t);
        console.log(t);
    };


    $("#thelist").append('<li>' + obj[0].Items[i].local + '</li>');

}
```

Comment: Have you parsed it using `JSON.parse`?

Comment: yes 

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(retorno);

Comment: It's a bit hard to see what's going on here. Either the example code is severely cut down, or the code is just a mess (or both). What does `.innerHTML` do there, for example? And what is that `eval()` supposed to do?

Comment: And where is `i` defined? Is it a nested loop?

Comment: and wtf is the `eval()` for? `eval()`s are dangerous, there's always a better way to do what you want without using it!

Comment: What I need is to add a string to read the number element of json
item1, item2

Comment: You know that you can use `for...in` to iterate over objects?

Comment: And you can also do obj[0].Items[i]["item" + somevar] where somevar iterates from 1 to n

Comment: The way you access the properties either. `obj[0].Items[i].'item' + a` should be `obj[0].Items[i]['item' + a]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make sure about this :

1)

```
 {
"Items": [
    {
        "local": "padaria",
        "item1": "leite",
        "item2": "pao"
    }],
}
```

you have comma after "]" (this you know :P)
that makes parser doesn't parse JSON

2)

```
     for (var a = 0; a < getObjectLength(obj[0].Items[i]); a++) {
     if (a > 0) {
         t = (obj[0].Items[i].
             'item' + a);
     }
```

you got syntax error ==> obj[0].Items[i].'item'

you can not use someobj.'key' like this

you can use someobj["key"] or someobj.key

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of problems with your code. I have fixed it in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/rVskE/)

The result of `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(retorno);` was an object with one item `"Items"`.
This meant that subsequent calls to `"Items"` had to be done as either `obj[0]` or `obj.Items` or `obj["Items"]`

But you were doing it as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj[0].Items.length; i++) {
```

Which was basically trying and failing to find `obj.Items.Items`!

The next issue was the way you were trying to access sequentially named properties `"item" + a`. Because the name lookup generation was dynamic, the Object Named-Key notation was the correct way to access it

That code had to be converted to `obj.Items[0].["item" + a]`

---

Now for some good practices:

- Your JSON has a trailing comma. Now although most browsers would parse it without any issues, older versions of IE will fail, and regardless, it is a bad practice.
- Because objects, functions, variables, etc in Javascript are scoped within a Function, some of your original code was vulnerable to what is defined as a [Hoisting/Scoping Issue](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html). Function declarations should not be placed in blocks. Either use a function expression or move the statement to the top of the outer function.

  So, the outer `for()` loop changes to either:

  ```
  //Move outside, into the outermost block
  function getObjectLength(obj) {
      //...
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.Items.length; i++) {
      //...
  }
  ```

  Or

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.Items.length; i++) {
      //Function Expression
      var getObjectLength = function (obj) {
          //...
      };

      //...
  }
  ```

  The problem with using the latter, Function Expression technique here is that it is a bad idea to create functions within a loop, as a new instance would be created on every iteration of the loop.

---

Fixed code:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(retorno);
for (var i = 0; i < obj.Items.length; i++) {
    function getObjectLength(obj) {
        var length = 0;
        for (var p in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                length++;
            }
        }
        return length;
    }
    var t;
    for (var a = 0; a < getObjectLength(obj.Items[i]); a++) {
        if (a > 0) {
            t = (obj.Items[i]['item' + a]);
        }
        console.log(obj.Items[i].t);
        console.log(t);
    };
    $("#thelist").append('<li>' + obj[0].Items[i].local + '</li>');
}
```